# How to write tests: Socket.io app unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, express, socket.io

I am trying to make simple chat app using socket.io. Manually it's working fine (via browser localhost:3000/) but I want to write unit tests to verify logic of the server. I don't know which tools/libraries to use for testing.

Here is my node server code:

## index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var socketCount = 0;

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socketCount++;

  console.log('new user connected');

  // Let all sockets know how many are connected
  io.emit('users connected', socketCount);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // Decrease the socket count on a disconnect, emit
    socketCount--;
    io.emit('users connected', socketCount);
    });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    // New message added, broadcast it to all sockets
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

});
```

And here is my html page:

## file: index.html

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <div class='footer'>
      <div id="usersConnected"></div>
      <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  ...
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#messages').val('');
        var socket = io();

        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });

        // New message emitted, add it to our list of current messages
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });

        // New socket connected, display new count on page
        socket.on('users connected', function(count){
          $('#usersConnected').html('Users connected: ' + count);
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem: How to do unit test with a "socket.io-client" if you don't know how long the server take to respond?.

I've solved so using *mocha* and *chai*:

```
var os = require('os');
var should = require("chai").should();
var socketio_client = require('socket.io-client');

var end_point = 'http://' + os.hostname() + ':8081';
var opts = {forceNew: true};

describe("async test with socket.io", function () {
this.timeout(10000);

it('Response should be an object', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var socket_client = socketio_client(end_point, opts);  

        socket_client.emit('event', 'ABCDEF');

        socket_client.on('event response', function (data) {
            data.should.be.an('object');
            socket_client.disconnect();
            done();
        });

        socket_client.on('event response error', function (data) {
            console.error(data);
            socket_client.disconnect();
            done();
            });
        }, 4000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Finally found a unit-testing example for socketIO that actually works.